# How to change the selection color in WPF? (ForeColor/BackColor)

Tags: c#, wpf, highlight, selection-color

In **WPF**, I don't really need any `SelectionOpacity` because it messes my desired color so I set it 1

```
<RichTextBox Background="#FF141414" Foreground="Gainsboro"
             SelectionOpacity="1" SelectionBrush="#FFFF7D00" >
</RichTextBox>
```

However, now when I highlight some text, I cannot see it.

[image: Hello World, this is a test.]

It turns out that the `SelectionBrush` changes the color for the **whole** thing, not just the background. (as I thought)
So, how is it possible to set each of the **ForeColor** and the **BackColor** selection (highlighting)?

Comment: `SelectionOpacity` IS what makes the text (which is being selected) visible. If you set it to 1 you won't be able to see what's behind. By definition, you can't see through non-transparent things.

Comment: I knew that. I just thought that the `SelectionOpacity` would set the opacity for only the *background* selection, not everything... so now I understand that the `SelectionBrush` is also for both Fore/Back Colors but I don't like it like that because I need to set special colors for each of them.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want something like in CSS where when you highlight text, you can specify the color of the highlight and the color of the text, right?

Comment: @user2619824 Yup, that's exactly what I want!